# How do I change app styles?

Tags: gtk

can anyone explain to me what I need to do in order to change the styles of a gtk application?

For example I want to keep the elementary gtk theme but change a detail here and there so I go to `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0` and look at the .css files. I know a little about css so I expect no problems there. But how do I know which elements have a given class and vice versa? So if I want to change the appearance of let's say the icon in *greeter* how do I know how to access that element in css?

Cheers